# Limiting the scope of a shared variable (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, oop, scope, javascript-objects

I would like to know if it is possible to have a variable with shared scope between two separate javascript files but not within the root document that references those javascript files.

For example, if I wanted to have a variable that held information about the size of an html element on page load, I could do something like this...

Within the root (index.html) document, I could declare the variable and give it a global scope:

```
<script>
  var elemWidth;
</script>

<script src="first.js"></script>
<script src="second.js"></script>
```

Within the first javascript file (first.js):

```
var elem = document.getElementById('myElem');
elemWidth = elem.style.width;
```

Within an additional javascript file (second.js):

```
var someDynamicValue = n; /* where 'n' is an integer that is given a calculated value */
if(elemWidth > someDynamicValue) { ... }
```

Using the above convention, the variable `elemWidth` is accessible in all three documents (index.html, first.js, second.js). But what if, for whatever reason, I did not want that variable to be accessible in the root document (index.html)? I only want it to be accessible and manipulatable in the two .js files. After all, it's really not needed in the root document (index.html) and I wouldn't necessarily need it in additional .js files (e.g. third.js).

Certain possibilities have come to me, but they all seem to break down at a certain point:

1. Declaring the variable within one of the two .js files would limit
   its scope to that document only. This just doesn't work.
2. Store the variable as a private property of an object that is declared in the root, and allow that property to be set/get only by the approved .js files

   - This might be possible by extending the prototype of the ancestor object within the external .js files to include getter/setter methods, but not providing those methods in the document root (which is where the ancestor would have to be declared)
   - I am not an OOP expert, so this approach might be fundamentally flawed. Feel free to correct me on this!
3. Consolidate the two javascript files into one, and declare the
   variable within that script. This would work, but I may not
   necessarily want to or be able to consolidate the separate .js files
   in certain circumstances.

Other than that, I am stumped by this question. At this time, I don't have a specific reason to need this functionality, but I can imagine it being useful in certain situations (i.e. additional security, quarantining variable values) and, of course, I am curious and would like to learn something new about JS & OOP through this example.

Perhaps it's just not possible in JavaScript - if so, please explain why :)

---

Update: I would like to expand on the idea of using object prototypal inheritance to possibly achieve this result. If we declare a class constructor, such as:

```
function ancestorObj() {
  var privateVar = 'secret';
}
```

And then extend this prototype with another constructor:

```
function inheritedObj() {
  this.getSecret = function() {
    return privateVar;
  }
}

inheritedObj.prototype = new ancestorObj();
```

We have now created an object class constructor that is an inherited instance of `ancestorObj` which contains a getter method that returns the private property of the prototype object. The default class constructor does not contain a getter method. The logic that follows is that only instances of the `inheritedObj` can get the value of this private property. Can we not then declare instances of `inheritedObj` only where needed (i.e. 'first.js' and 'second.js'), thereby limiting the scope of the `privateVar` property?

Again, OOP is not my forte, so this may be easily dismissed as not possible or otherwise incorrect. If so, please explain why.

Comment: I'd investigate module loading patterns using the likes of requirejs. http://www.requirejs.org/ . This may give you some alternatives to explore regarding injecting scripts as modules into other modules etc.

Answer (score 4):

Ultimately there's nothing you can do to make the symbol completely private to two code units imported from separate `<script>` blocks. The only relationships such code can have are via global symbols, and if code in two scripts can find your "private" property, any other code can too.

Probably the best thing to do is keep it as a property of some global namespace you claim, or under one you're already using (like a framework).

Comment: That is my current understanding - that only global variables are accessible across disparate scripts. I was hoping there was a methodology that bends that rule, allowing the scope to be more specifically controlled. I even toyed with the idea of requiring a 'password' (in the form of an argument passed to a function) in order to set/get the value of said variable :D

Answer (score 3):

In your case it'd wrap it into a jQuery method like `$.fn.methodName = function { var leaveMeAlone = true; };`

Comment: If you do that, then *nothing* can see "leaveMeAlone".

Comment: Anything in that method can.

Comment: why introduce jQuery in the first place is my question

Comment: Well yes, that's true, but the problem to be solved is how to make the symbol visible to code imported at the global level in separate `<script>` blocks. Of course your function could be extended to provide a getter/setter API, I guess.

Comment: @Pointy Regarding the second part of your comment - how would this differ from creating an ancestor object that contains a private property and only allowing inherited instances of that object class to set/get the value of that private variable? (this was idea #2 in my OP)

Comment: @BrianS Well there's really no way to have anything like a "private" object property in JavaScript. You can ensure certain behavior is followed when property values are updated, but if any code can find the setter function, then all code can find it.

Comment: I see. My understanding was that something like  
`function myObj() {
  var privateProp = 'secret';  
}`
as opposed to `this.privateProp = 'not a secret';` would mean that property value could only be referenced/changed via a getter/setter method of that object. By leaving out the getter/setter in the ancestor, but adding to its prototypal inheritance later on with an extended instance of the myObj class, you would be able to set/get the private property only where the extended object was defined (i.e. not the root document)